# Cascaded filter rejection performance

Tags: electrical

If two filters are in cascade and each has a certain rejection at a certain frequency offset.

We know that a filter rejects frequencies  by mismatch so at this offset we do not have a 50 ohm match and filter2 would be a load to filter1 when the reference plane is the input of filter1

question : can one add the 2 rejections and consider that this would be the total combined rejection?

Comment: I recommend to rewrite the question a little bit, as it isn't utterly clear, what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t just connect two passive filters in cascade and  then add up their designed attenuations. To work like they are designed, they need to “see” fifty ohms at the input and output, as you suspect.

Placing some kind of active buffer between them could do that, or placing a fairly large attenuating “pad” between them would also do that.

Comment: "A fairly large attenuator" is going to introduce insertion loss that cannot be tolerated in the current design. Would then the only way to estimate the total rejection be simulation using the right tool?

Comment: Hello, Ali: yes, Spice would be an easy way.